# WP get locale in plugin code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, locale, cart

Hy i am trying to get current language inside of plugin code. I have try with get_locale() but it always give me just en_us. I have try to find solution on WordPress code references but did not found anything that work.

In question is plugin WooCommerce, file wc-cart-functions.php
There are lines:

```
$added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
```

and

```
$message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
```

I want to get this result:

```
if($language == 'hr') { $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s je dodan u košaricu.', '%s su dodani u košaricu.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
    } else { $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) ); }
if($language == 'hr') { $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( home_url().'/kosarica' ), esc_html__( 'Pogledaj košaricu', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
        } else { $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) ); }
```

Normally, i would solve this by geting language from URL, but that website doesnt have language in URL.

Comment: I have forgot to mention, website use Polylang plugin for languages.

Comment: Oops, meant to add that as a comment, but will leave it as an answer. Especially if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the polylang plugin, see this site: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/ .. you probably need to use `pll_current_language()` which should return current language.

Comment: I have try, it works inside theme files, but not inside plugin files.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
    $language = pll_current_language('slug');
    if($language == 'hr') { 
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s je dodan u košaricu.', '%s su dodani u košaricu.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );} else { 
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) ); }
    if($language == 'hr') { 
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( home_url().'/kosarica' ), esc_html__( 'Pogledaj košaricu', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );} else { 
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) ); }
```

Comment: I need only translate these two sentences. Boss wont let me to buy plugin for that :/

Comment: These code work inside theme files, but not inside plugin files. Thank you very much for your effort, all of you! I will have to do something else to get info about current language inside plugin file. Thank you again, i appreciate your effort!